# Maptree Decision Tree plot in R: Showing Distribution at each Node

Tags: r, tree, classification, mean, median

I generated a decision tree using the package *tree*.
I am plotting it using *maptree*. My code looks like this:

```
    library(tree)
    library(maptree)
    treeTree =  tree(fmla,data = df, control = tree.control(n,mincut = 50))
    prune.tree(treeTree,  eps = 10^(-3) )
    pdf( paste(fName, varName,"tree", "tree.pdf", sep = "_") )
      missc = deviance(treeTree, detail=TRUE)
      text(treeTree, splits = TRUE,  label = "yval", all = FALSE,
      pretty = NULL, digits = getOption("digits") - 3,adj = 
      par("adj"), xpd = TRUE)
      title(main=varName)
    dev.off()
```

Unfortunately, this seems to plot the median at each end node. So I get a tree that looks like this:

```
| \
|  \
|   \ 
NO   NO
| \   
|  \
|   \ 
NO   NO
```

I.e. a lot of splitting but we always end up at NO.

This is because for my outcome variable (representing risk for sick patients) the median risk is always 0.

I would like to show the mean at each node, or even better, the fraction of outcomes for each option.

I have read the maptree manual but can't figure out how do to do this.